# How to get dates from these numbers

Tags: python, date, datetime, delphi

I have problems to convert some timestamps to readable dates.
Unfortunately I don't know how they are encoded. I was just told, that these dates were created with delphi as a `System.TDate` object.
I know which date they represent, but I can not figure out how to convert them.

```
What I have -> date they represent
131006721 -> 1999-01-01
126550273 -> 1931-01-01
130875649 -> 1997-01-01
```

Comment: It's the number of days that have passed since 30 Dec 1899. ([Doc](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_TDateTime.html))

Comment: I have read this too, but the timestamp is too big to represent days.

Comment: seem to be 2^16 units of time per 365 days

Comment: Yes. The first value is a few years in the future. 19 Mar 32904 to be precise. Or the person telling you this is a `TDate` wasn't right.

Comment: Numbers converted to hex: `7CF0101`,`7CD0101`,`78B0101`, so maybe first two bytes = year, third = month, fouth = day.

Comment: I think, the representation is like `(year * (2^16)) + (month * (2^8)) + (day * (2^0))`. for  example, if we take first one, its `(1999 * (2^16)) + (1 * (2^8)) + (1 * (2^0)) = 131006721`

Comment: Who would waste bits like that? I can stuff day and month into 9 bit already (instead of 16), which the [DOS DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-dosdatetimetofiletime) demonstrated for decades...

Comment: @AmigoJack: given that a Python date object requires 32 bytes, 32 bits are relatively efficient :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With provided dates, The representation seems like,

```
(year * (2^16)) + (month * (2^8)) + (day * (2^0))
```

For example, if we take first one,

```
(1999 * (2^16)) + (1 * (2^8)) + (1 * (2^0)) = 131006721
```

Hence you can revert this like below to get corresponding dates from number representations.

```py
reps=[131006721,126550273,130875649]
for a in reps:
    print(a//(2**16),(a%(2**16))//(2**8),((a%(2**16))%(2**8))//(2**0))
```

**Output**

```
1999 1 1
1931 1 1
1997 1 1
```

Comment: nice back and forth conversion! feels a bit clumsy with `struct`

Comment: Thanks! I still can not understand why the dates are stored so complex in this specific software.

Comment: @AndiLeni: it saves memory... a Python `date` object would require x8 more (32 bytes per date)

Comment: @MrFuppes you are right, but in this case I receive the date as a simple string. '1999-01-01' would have been just as good.

Answer (score 2):

as @BrakNicku commented, most likely you have 2 bytes representing the year and 1 byte each representing day / month:

```
import struct

ints = (131006721, 126550273, 130875649)

for i in ints:
    # to bytes
    b = struct.pack('>i', i) 
    # bytes 1 & 2 to year (as 16 bit int), byte 3 to month, byte 4 to day
    year, month, day = struct.unpack('>h', b[:2])[0], b[2], b[3]
    print(i, '->', year, month, day)
    
# 131006721 -> 1999 1 1
# 126550273 -> 1931 1 1
# 130875649 -> 1997 1 1
```